# Is it more or less efficient to use the async keyword along with starting the method on a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a program that downloads alot of data from the internet and saves it to my local db using the Entity Framework. I have this sample code below. Is it more efficient for me to start the method on a new thread and also use the async keyword when it is saving the model data or is this less efficient.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DBModel model = new DBModel())
        {
            model.Database.Connection.Open();

            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => downloadData(model));
            task.Wait();
        }

    }

public static async Task<string> downloadData(DBModel model)
    {
        // do something first
        await model.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: In this case `StartNew` is superfluous. Also your example is broken, your code won't do what you expect it to. I mean process will terminate as soon as you start `downloadData` because you're not waiting on the task. Can you bring a better example?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I just wrote this just to try to better explain what I am thinking of doing. This project is in the planning stages right now so I don't have production code to show. I will better edit my code

Comment: In addition to Sriram's points, it's worse even than what he wrote: not only are you not waiting on the task, the task itself doesn't wait on the `async` method, and so is likely to complete before the actual work has completed. As far as the basic question goes: if you already have an `async` method, there's no point in wrapping that in a `Task`. Just `await` the `async` method call itself.

Comment: Now my comment became obsolete but @Peter's comment stands.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I edited my code so that the task is waiting properly or at least I believe I did it properly. Overall I'm just trying to find out if doing this in production code is more efficient than just doing one or the other. I don't have any real code to show yet I'm afraid

Comment: @user3610374 No it doesn't. task returned by `StartNew` represents a call to `downloadData` and it will finish as soon as first `await` hit inside `downloadData` because that's when the async method returns. If you need to wait till `downloadData` is completed you need to use `StartNew(..).UnWrap()`. All of this is not required you can simply call `downloadData.Wait();` instead.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you! This answers my questions very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it more efficient...

That's the wrong question. It's better to first consider which is more *correct*, and then search for more efficient methods once you have a proven performance problem in production code.

`async` methods should be used when doing operations that are naturally asynchronous. This includes any kind of I/O, such as downloading data from the Internet and EF.

Multithreading should be used if you want to free up the current thread when doing operations that are CPU-bound. You can use `Task.Run` (not `StartNew`, *please*) to push work off to a background thread.

In your situation, just using `async`/`await` is more correct.

Comment: What about using the parallel programming library in .net? Would that also work just as well or better? @stephencleary

Comment: @user3610374: **If** you have CPU-bound work to do, then yes, `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ works quite nicely. Note that your example is not CPU-bound, so you should not use the TPL.